# Whats the best way to handle Login\Logout buttons with Nuxt to avoid flashing content?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm new to Nuxt, but I have a bootstrap header with the standard v-if="authenticated" kinda state for login\logout buttons.

The auth provider is firebase which has a onAuthStateChanged method that I use to set (or reset) the user property in the state store.

So page loads, I see the login button, onAuthStateChanged runs, sets the user, then login disappears and logout button shows up (can see the Vuex events from base->set as well).

Question is, what am I doing fundamentally wrong such that I'm getting this flashing state.  Is the only way to handle this to work with localStorage? ...should I NOT be storing the user in the state.store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save it in the store. But make no mistake because when reloading you have to set the token value using localstorage.

[These are very good explanations](https://blog.sqreen.com/authentication-best-practices-vue/)

Comment: But is this BEST way like there's no reason to do anything in session storage or anything? (Coming from a non-node backend).

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what you want to do?

Comment: Just simply be able to initialize the state knowing if someone is logged in or not right away to avoid the flash... Since firebase' method runs like a second AFTER everything has loaded. Like with PHP or asp or whatever this is all just internally handled with cookies and stuff, seems with nuxt is pretty manual?